# PHP/Zend: Ajax Paging: How do I get the path of the file including a class I've got in a given class object? Or correctly load the object from Cache?

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching

First, because I'm not sure whether it's clear what I mean:
I have an class object given in a function and I need the path of the file, this class is declared, because this object is stored in the cache and to load it, I need to include the file the class is declared in to unserialize it.

Second, that's what I'm trying to do:
I'm trying to write a pagination, the object of the model class, the select object and the limit is given to the constructor. The basic paging already works, I'm now trying to build an ajax paging, the given objects and the limit is cached and the request and should be loaded by the ajax request to return the needed data. The problem is like described above: I need to include the containing file first, but I've got not path.

**Question:**
How do I get this path to include the class or do you have any ideas how I could solve this problem differently?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
I've used the ReflectionClass to get the complete filepath:

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($model);
$directory = $reflectionClass->getFileName();
```

$directory contains:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\[...]\application\models\DbTable\BdUsers.php
```